# Why is the Play framework (1.2.5) escaping my JavaScript?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to integrate Olark into my application.  To do this, I have to put this into my HTML just before the closing body tag:

```
<!-- begin olark code --><script data-cfasync="false" type='text/javascript'>/*{literal}<![CDATA[*/
window.olark||(function(c) ... "identify"]});
/* custom configuration goes here (www.olark.com/documentation) */
olark.identify('redacted my code');/*]]>{/literal}*/</script><noscript><a href="someurl" title="Contact us" target="_blank">Questions? Feedback?</a> powered by <a href="http://www.olark.com?welcome" title="Olark live chat software">Olark live chat software</a></noscript><!-- end olark code -->
```

So I put this in my view.  But, all that gets served is

```
<!-- begin olark code --><script data-cfasync="false" type='text/javascript'>//</script><noscript><a href="https://www.olark.com/site/redacted my code/contact" title="Contact us" target="_blank">Questions? Feedback?</a> powered by <a href="http://www.olark.com?welcome" title="Olark live chat software">Olark live chat software</a></noscript><!-- end olark code -->
```

The entire script is being converted into one `//`.  From looking at Play's docs, I can't see what is causing this.  Any tips?

The escaping starts at `/*{literal}<![CDATA[*/` and ends at `/*]]>{/literal}*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  `*{` `}*` is a comment.  By replacing the `/*{literal}<![CDATA[*/` with `/${"*"}{literal}<![CDATA[*/` the problem was fixed.